# Chrome web inspector

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, web-inspector

I use Chrome web inspector to inspect all variables.

When I hover my mouse over a variable a yellow popup box appears and I can see what that variable is referencing to.

Sometimes it's an object that has a lot of keys. Is there a way to make this yellow box larger?

Comment: I wonder, does "add watch" to the right do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run chrome with your own custom dev tools
http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/contributing.html

In short,

1. Download devtools_frontend.zip
2. Extract the files (possibly to C:\src\chrome\devtools_frontend)
3. Open Popover.js
4. Find the line where it says:

   ```
   preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, 50);
   ```

   and replace it with

   ```
   preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, 500);
   preferredHeight = Math.max(preferredHeight, 500);
   ```

   this will make the minimum size of the popover 500px X 500px
5. Run chrome with your custome devtools:

   chrome.exe --debug-devtools-frontend=C:\src\chrome\devtools_frontend